# Writing array elements to an external memory location in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

I wish to write elements from a 2D array to a particular memory location.
I tried this simply with a 1D array:

```
char arr[3]= {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
int i=0;
uint32_t p= 0x40000000;
for(i=0; i<3;i++)
{
    *p=&arr[];
    p++
}
```

It gives an error that operand of * must be a pointer.

How can I write array elements one by one to the location 0x40000000?

Comment: `int p= 0x40;` shoule be `int *p= 0x40;`, but what you are trying is not recommended operation

Comment: `*p=&arr[];` is wrong. Maybe you want `*p=arr[i];` ?

Comment: `p++` -> `p++;` or `++p;`

Comment: yes *p=arr[i] ; @4386472

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to write bytes from an array into arbitrary memory.
This is doable, but you should be sure you know what you're doing before running this kind of code.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(){
  char arr[3]= {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
  int i=0;
  uint32_t* p= (uint32_t*) 0x40000000;
  for(i=0; i<3;i++)
  {
    *p=arr[i];
    p++;
  }
}
```

In particular, unless you have a reason to believe there's something valid to write to at address `0x40000000` on whatever system your code is running on, it will segfault with high probability.

Comment: Given the data in `arr` the pointer type might be `char*` or even better `volatile char *`.

Comment: @Gerhardh I completely agree. I'm merely providing a minimum modification of the OP's code to compile, without trying to guess exactly what they want.

Comment: thanks for your input. 0x4000000 is the address of external RAM i am using.. i need to write the data coming in an array from to this location for temporary storage and then process it.. i'll try the above modification and comment whether its giving desired output

Comment: Using `uint32_t *`, the code will write 4 bytes (3 of them zero) to locations 0x40000000..0x40000003, another 4 bytes to locations 0x40000004..0x40000007, and another 4 bytes to locations 0x40000008..0x4000000B.  This is not the same as writing 3 bytes to locations 0x40000000..0x40000002.